# Recursive Matrix Multiplication Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, c, recursion, matrix

Can I improve on this any further. Is there a prettier way of passing the array sizes?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void matrix_addition(size_t n, int A[n][n], int B[n][n], int C[2*n][2*n], size_t c_start, size_t c_end) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            C[i+c_start][j+c_end] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void recursive_matrix_multiply(
        size_t l, size_t n, int A[l][l], int B[l][l], int C[n][n],
        size_t a_r_start, size_t a_r_end, size_t a_c_start, size_t a_c_end, 
        size_t b_r_start, size_t b_r_end, size_t b_c_start, size_t b_c_end
    ) {
    if(n == 1) {
        C[0][0] = A[a_r_start][a_c_start]*B[b_r_start][b_c_start];
    } else {
        int m = n/2;
        int C1[m][m];
        int C2[m][m];

        recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C1, a_r_start, a_r_end-m, a_c_start, a_c_end-m, b_r_start, b_r_end-m, b_c_start, b_c_end-m);
        recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C2, a_r_start, a_r_end-m, a_c_start+m, a_c_end, b_r_start+m, b_r_end, b_c_start, b_c_end-m);
        
        matrix_addition(m, C1, C2, C, 0, 0);
        
        recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C1, a_r_start, a_r_end-m, a_c_start, a_c_end-m, b_r_start, b_r_end-m, b_c_start+m, b_c_end);
        recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C2, a_r_start, a_r_end-m, a_c_start+m, a_c_end, b_r_start+m, b_r_end, b_c_start+m, b_c_end);

        matrix_addition(m, C1, C2, C, 0, m);

        recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C1, a_r_start+m, a_r_end, a_c_start, a_c_end-m, b_r_start, b_r_end-m, b_c_start, b_c_end-m);
        recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C2, a_r_start+m, a_r_end, a_c_start+m, a_c_end, b_r_start+m, b_r_end, b_c_start, b_c_end-m);

        matrix_addition(m, C1, C2, C, m, 0);

        recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C1, a_r_start+m, a_r_end, a_c_start, a_c_end-m, b_r_start, b_r_end-m, b_c_start+m, b_c_end);
        recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C2, a_r_start+m, a_r_end, a_c_start+m, a_c_end, b_r_start+m, b_r_end, b_c_start+m, b_c_end);
    
        matrix_addition(m, C1, C2, C, m, m);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int A[4][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, { 0, 0, 1, 1 }, {1, 1, 0, 0}};
    int B[4][4] = {{2, 2, 4, 4}, {4, 1, 1, 4}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}};
    int C[4][4];
    
    recursive_matrix_multiply(4, 4, A, B, C, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            printf("C[%i][%i] = %i, ", i, j, C[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

It currently works as intended but I'm looking to beautify this a bit. Even an improvement on variable naming would be appreciated. I'm trying to build up a portfolio so if you saw this from a professional standpoint what would you think?

Comment: Is necessary to implement the multiplication in a recursive way ? If not, your matrix multiplication algorithm would take 10 lines.

Comment: @MiguelAvila Yes, I'm avoiding for loops and practicing divide and conquer algorithms. This is really a warm up for Strassens algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caution: Assessment of *advanced matrix multiplication* is non-trivial. See [Introduction to Performance Engineering &
Matrix Multiplication](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-172-performance-engineering-of-software-systems-fall-2018/lecture-slides/MIT6_172F18_lec1.pdf) for starters, in particular the part about cache access patterns and similarities therein between tiling and recursive decomposition on one hand and Strassen&Cie․ on the other.

---

Public/main items of a program should be self-explanatory, or come with a description.
I'm under the impression that as presented `recursive_matrix_multiply()` (and consequently `matrix_multiply()` in the self-answer) only work for square matrices sized the same power of 2.

`improvement on variable naming`
I can see that telling names aren't short, and only short names keep the length of calls with many parameters and expressions with many primaries from getting out of hand.
I'd much prefer terse names to be introduced with a comment.
I take the names *A*, *B*, and *C* to be conventional for binary operations.
In `matrix_addition()`, `c_start` looks plausible, but is it *c_* for *column* or *referring to matrix/parameter C*?
`c_end` is worse - I don't see any *end* it refers to, just the *offset for second dimension index in C*.
I can live with (I guess I'm still with [doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html))

```
/// suitable to hold one matrix dimension
typedef size_t md;

void matrix_addition( ///< Let part of C = A + B.
    md n, int A[][n], int B[][n], int C[][2*n],
    md fo, ///< first dimension offset into C
    md so ///< second dimension offset into C
    ) {
```

`I'm avoiding for loops` beyond reason -
recursion inside a one nested loop sure is shorter and, in my eyes, more readable.
Taking names from [Ivor Denham-Dyson's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/244182/93149):

```
    for (md ro = 0 ; ro <= m ; ro += m)
        for (md co = 0 ; co <= m ; co += m) {
            recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C1, ar+ro, ac, br, bc+co);
            recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C2, ar+ro, ac+m, br+m, bc+co);

            matrix_addition_partition(n, m, C1, C2, C, ro, co);
        }
```

Comment: I'm moved on to the suggested text. Such a good resource thanks

Answer (score 0):

All of the endpoints are redundant. If anyone can add anything else I'd still appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void matrix_addition_partition(size_t n, size_t m, int A[m][m], int B[m][m], int C[n][n], size_t start, size_t end) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            C[i+start][j+end] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void recursive_matrix_multiply(
        size_t l, size_t n, int A[l][l], int B[l][l], int C[n][n],
        size_t ar, size_t ac, size_t br, size_t cb
    ) {
    if(n == 1) {
        C[0][0] = A[ar][ac]*B[br][cb];
    } else {
        int m = n>>1;
        int C1[m][m], C2[m][m];

        recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C1, ar, ac, br, cb);
        recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C2, ar, ac+m, br+m, cb);

        matrix_addition_partition(n, m, C1, C2, C, 0, 0);
        
        recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C1, ar, ac, br, cb+m);
        recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C2, ar, ac+m, br+m, cb+m);

        matrix_addition_partition(n, m, C1, C2, C, 0, m);

        recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C1, ar+m, ac, br, cb);
        recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C2, ar+m, ac+m, br+m, cb);

        matrix_addition_partition(n, m, C1, C2, C, m, 0);

        recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C1, ar+m, ac, br, cb+m);
        recursive_matrix_multiply(l, m, A, B, C2, ar+m, ac+m, br+m, cb+m);
    
        matrix_addition_partition(n, m, C1, C2, C, m, m);

    }
}

void matrix_multiply(size_t n, int A[n][n], int B[n][n], int C[n][n]) {
    recursive_matrix_multiply(n, n, A, B, C, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}


int main()
{
    int A[4][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}};
    int B[4][4] = {{2, 2, 4, 4}, {4, 1, 1, 4}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}};
    int C[4][4];
    
    matrix_multiply(4, A, B, C);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            printf("C[%i][%i] = %i, ", i, j, C[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is hard to parallelize. you can't spawn any threads inside of the recursion as it will create a fork bomb.

Comment: (There was a "finger rot" changing `bc` to `cb`.)